# How to read a value that coincide with a specific string inside a text file?

Tags: c, file, text

I have the following text file:

```
1 Feb Jane Auckland LF1 190.21
2 Feb Jane Auckland BDHIWAY 390.62 
7 Feb Adeeva Sharif LSZ 2000.00
8 Feb Adeeva Sharif LF2 52.00
4 Feb Jane Auckland ILZERO 101.03 
9 Feb Jerome Velence ILFIVE 4110.00
```

As you can see there are three people (Jane Auckland, Adeeva Sharif, and Jerome Velence) in the text file however each have value attached to them and spread around the text file being separated by other people..

What I want to do is read the text file at only one person at a time. However I want their coinciding values (the last value) to add together so I can put them through my tax function and print a pay slip and cheque for each person. It will look similar to this:

```
Pay slip for Jane Auckland from file examplep1.txt
+-------------------------+
| Commission : $   681.86 |
| Tax        : $     0.00 |
|              ---------- |
| Net Pay    : $   681.86 |
+-------------------------+

OFFICIAL CHEQUE FOR BANK 'BBPL'
Please pay Jane Auckland an amount of $681.86
[  ]       WIC - 420 1337 911

Pay slip for Adeeva Sharif from file examplep1.txt
+-------------------------+
| Commission : $  2052.00 |
| Tax        : $   101.65 |
|              ---------- |
| Net Pay    : $  1950.35 |
+-------------------------+

OFFICIAL CHEQUE FOR BANK 'BBPL'
Please pay Adeeva Sharif an amount of $1950.35
[  ]       WIC - 420 1337 911

Pay slip for Jerome Velence from file examplep1.txt
+-------------------------+
| Commission : $  4110.00 |
| Tax        : $   631.78 |
|              ---------- |
| Net Pay    : $  3478.23 |
+-------------------------+

OFFICIAL CHEQUE FOR BANK 'BBPL'
Please pay Jane Auckland an amount of $3478.23
[  ]       WIC - 420 1337 911
```

Here is my tax function:

```
    double calculateTax(double income)
    {
    double centsPerDollar;
    double initialTax;
    double minimumTax;

    income = round(income); //Rounds income to the nearest interger.

    if (income >= 0 && income <= 1517) //First tax bracket.
    {
        centsPerDollar = 0.00;
        initialTax = 0.00;
        minimumTax = 0.00;

        tax = 0.00;
        taxedIncome = income;
    }
    else if (income >= 1518 && income <= 3083) //Second tax bracket.
    {
        centsPerDollar = 0.19;
        initialTax = 0.00;
        minimumTax = 1517.00;

        tax = (income - minimumTax) * centsPerDollar + initialTax;
        taxedIncome = income - ((income - minimumTax) * centsPerDollar + initialTax);
    }
    else if (income >= 3084 && income <= 6667) //Third tax bracket.
    {
        centsPerDollar = 0.325;
        initialTax = 298.00;
        minimumTax = 3083.00;

        tax = (income - minimumTax) * centsPerDollar + initialTax;
        taxedIncome = income - ((income - minimumTax) * centsPerDollar + initialTax);
    }
    else if (income >= 6668 && income <= 15000) //Fourth tax bracket.
    {
        centsPerDollar = 0.37;
        initialTax = 1462.00;
        minimumTax = 6667.00;

        tax = (income - minimumTax) * centsPerDollar + initialTax;
        taxedIncome = income - ((income - minimumTax) * centsPerDollar + initialTax);
    }
    else if (income >= 15001) //Fifth tax bracket.
    {
        centsPerDollar = 0.45;
        initialTax = 4546.00;
        minimumTax = 15000.00;

        tax = (income - minimumTax) * centsPerDollar + initialTax;
        taxedIncome = income - ((income - minimumTax) * centsPerDollar + initialTax);
    }
    else { fprintf(stderr, "Must be a positive number."); } //Error check for negative numbers.
}
```

In summary of what I want to do is to individualise each person with their own values and put said values through my tax function and print out a pay slip and cheque for each person as shown in the example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First problem with your text file, name components are separated by the same separator that separates fields. Use a different separator, like a tab `'\t'` or a semicolon `';'` so that it's not ambigous.

Comment: There's no standard function to jump straight to your end goal. Best if you break up the process into file parsing and then final result collation. That is,  read each line, parse it, store the parsed info and then collate the final result after the file has been fully parsed.

Comment: You may be making the problem difficult by your approach. Why not read all values from the file into an *array of struct* and then sort the array by name and simply sum the values for each name? You can even create a separate struct holding the name, and sum for each person that you populate from the detailed list read from the file.

Comment: Note: No need for `income >= 1518 &&` , `income >= 3084 && ` ...

Comment: How come Jane Auckland gets two paychecks from the given sample data?  Oh, I see: it is just an incomplete search-n-replace operation.  Never mind!

Comment: Did you consider using `sort -k3,3 -k4,4` on the data file (possibly with other sort options if, for example, the month is significant), so that your C code doesn't have to futz with that part of the processing?

Answer (score 0):

> How to read a value that coincide with a specific string inside a text file?

Read each line, parse it and test if the value matches the specified string.

Can use `"%n"` to store the number of characters scanned and test for success.

```
// open the file
// TBD code 

char buf[100];
while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, istream)) {
  int count;
  char mon[100], first[100], last[100], code[100];
  double money;
  int n = 0; 
  // 1 Feb Jane Auckland LF1 190.21
  sscanf(buf, "%d %s %s %s %s %lf %n", &count, mon, first, last, code, &money, &n);
  if (n > 0 && buf[n] == 0) {
    if (strcmp(code, "specific string") == 0) {
      // found it!             
      printf("%s\n", code);
    }
  }
}

fclose(istream);
```

Confident OP can handle the rest of the needed code to lookup the tax and print the output.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution. I have changed the file a little to remove ambiguity and used `';'` as the field separator for each row.

This code is commented and every detail is explained

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct Record {
    char date[6];
    char name[50];
    char type[25];
    float value;
};

int
compare_records(const void *const lhs, const void *const rhs)
{
    /* Compare the names, since this is the field
     * you want to use for matching
     */
    return strcmp(((struct Record *) lhs)->name, ((struct Record *) rhs)->name);
}

int
read_next_record(FILE *file, struct Record *record)
{
    int result;
    /* Simply extract the record from the file.
     *
     * There are many valid methods, some are
     * more robust than this, but this is fast
     * and straight forward given your data.
     */
    result = fscanf(file, "%5[^;];%49[^;];%24[^;];%f\n",
        record->date, record->name, record->type, &record->value);
    return (result == 4);
}

void
display_pay_slip_for(const char *const name, struct Record *first, size_t count)
{
    float value;
    struct Record *next;
    struct Record *found;
    struct Record *final;
    struct Record key;

    /* Make a reacord with the name you want to find */
    strcpy(key.name, name);
    /* Perform a binary search on the data set */
    found = bsearch(&key, first, count, sizeof(*first), compare_records);
    if (found == NULL)
        return;
    /* Compute where the last record is */
    final = first + count - 1;
    /* Store the value in the current record */
    value = found->value;
    /* Search for records appearing BEFORE the
     * on found with binary search and take the
     * important data from them.
     */
    for (next = found - 1 ; ((next >= first) && (compare_records(next, found) == 0)) ; --next)
        value += next->value;
    /* Search for records appearing AFTER the
     * on found with binary search and take the
     * important data from them.
     */
    for (next = found + 1 ; ((next <= final) && (compare_records(next, found) == 0)) ; ++next)
        value += next->value;
    /* Display the result */
    fprintf(stdout, "Total for `%s' -> %f\n", name, value);
}

void
display_file(const char *const filename)
{
    FILE *file;
    struct Record records[100];
    size_t count;

    file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file != NULL) /* Check that the file DID open */
    {
        count = 0;
        /* Read records from the file, the specific method for reading
         * is irrelevant, if you have a function that does it the
         * actual implementation of such function is flexible as long
         * as it does what it has to do
         */
        while (read_next_record(file, &records[count]) != 0)
            ++count;
        /* Sort the records to be able to do a binary search.
         * It's not important for a few records, but many records
         * it's really important as it improves performance
         * dramatically.
         */
        qsort(records, count, sizeof(*records), compare_records);
        /* Simply, call a function where you search for all
         * the records associated with a given "match" in this
         * case the person name, and display the result.
         */
        display_pay_slip_for("Jane Auckland", records, count);
        display_pay_slip_for("Adeeva Sharif", records, count);
        display_pay_slip_for("Jerome Velence", records, count);

        /* Of course never forget this */
        fclose(file);
    }
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "error openning `%s'\n", filename);
}

int
main(void)
{
    display_file("data.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

The only thing missing you have already implemented and you can use it with this code if you want.